# How to make jQuery filter works when html code contains random text?

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing

I use ajax request to get data from my webpage:

```
    $.get("http://localhost/test.php", {id: myid}, 
    function(data) {

       var $r = $(data);
       alert($r.filter('.info').text());

   });
```

And everything works correctly when test.php contains correctly made lines like this:

```
<span class="info">show me this info</span>
```

But when something shows up without formatting - e.g. error or random text in front of correct html code:

```
error text without formatting or random text
<span class="info">show me this info</span>
```

then ajax request is no longer parsing other lines to get values from `.info`. And I get empty alert. Why is that? And how to prevent such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the returned HTML in an element:

```
$.get("http://localhost/test.php", {id: myid}, 
function(data) {

   var $r = $("<div>").html(data);
   alert($r.filter('.info').text());

});
```

This will create a new `div` element and set the html of it to your HTML (regardless of what it contains).

The problem is that you have top level elements it does not know how to parse as HTML. jQuery's `$(anystring)` method assumes a text string is a *selector*, *unless* it starts with a `<` element. If it starts with a `<` it will try to construct DOM elements from it.